# Cannot create cookies on HTTPS site

Tags: php, cookies

I am having problems getting a PHP script to write a cookie on an HTTPS site when the same script rules fine on an HTTP one.

The Code:

```
setcookie('testme', 'test', time()+7200, '/', '', isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]), true);
```

In fact I have tried many different ways but none work. This is just a simple version.

I have also tried:

```
$temp = 'example.co.uk';
setcookie('testme', 'test', time()+7200, '/', $temp, isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]), true);
```

Found a fix, I moved the code to the top and it worked fine, I have no idea why it was working on the test server as I know headers must be at the top. Sorry I was misleading people by looking in the wrong place.

Comment: `isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"])` that is a false positive.

Comment: Param 5 should be `example.com` shouldn't it

Comment: OK I have striped back the statement to a straight forward create cookie and still no luck -         setcookie('im_cookie', '666');

Comment: Let's tidy up this Q/A.  Please answer your question to explain you merely moved your setcookie and condition statement to the top of your file.  Otherwise, consider deleting the question entirely.

Comment: @mickmackusa I would answer it but I have no option to do so. All I can do is edit the question or add a comment.

Comment: @DaveG okay, very well then.